# What are some good design practices for cross-platform certificate storage?

Tags: certificates, linux, key-management, .net, windows-dpapi

Question from the Bouncy Castle development list:

> At present we use the Windows certificate store as:
>
> ```
> var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
> store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly | OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
> var certs = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, subjectName,
> true);
> ```
>
> We’d like to switch to something that’s more cross platform (esp Linux
>   compatible). What are some good design patterns for a secure, cross
>   platform certificate storage? We need to store RSA and EC certificates
>   as well as their respective private keys (if they exist in the
>   password protected PFX).